# Is it possible to output to a csv file with multiple sheets?

Tags: java, excel, csv

I need to output data to a CSV file from Java, but in that csv file I hope to create multiple sheets so that data can be organized in a better way. After some googling, it seems this is not possible. A CSV file can only receive one-sheet data.

Is this true? If yes, what would be the options? Thank you.

Comment: Is it an option to add an extra column to your csv file that identifies what group that data belongs to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file is interpreted a sequence of characters which comply to some [standardization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Standardization), therefor it cannot contains more than one sheet. You can output your data in a Excel file that contains more than one sheet using the [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) api.

Comment: Probably  I have to use this. Thanks.

Comment: @martin It's the most popular java api to deal with MS Document,  easy and reliable.

Answer (score -2):

Comma Separated Value lists are generally created in plain text files, which do not have multiple pages. What you could do instead is create multiple CSV files, but if you really have a lot of data, a data base might be your best bet.